# How to capture the I2S signal via Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: adc, raspberry-pi, i2s

I would like to capture the I2S data from ADC CS5340 by raspberry Pi zero, but I could not find relevant I2S API to use in raspberry pi zero. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: You need a Linux kernel driver for your adc. Then the chip appears as an audio device to Linux.

Comment: Thanks! @Kartman I found a I2S slave driver on github and it works.